# WordPress mouse over select option

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a drop down list that has a mouse over function with content from the datbase.
I'm stuck on the 'load content from the database' part

Here is a Fiddle of where I currently am 
http://jsfiddle.net/TJ6Fz/22/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('option').hover(function(){
    var optionVal = $(this).text();
   $('#display').html(optionVal)

})

})
```

I found this Fiddle and does exactly what I want.

I'm not a star in JQuery. So if anyone would be such a gentleman to provide me with a jquery solution where I could get values from my database I would me thrilled,

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you are looking for the solution like, you need to take the values from database depends on the change happen in the select box. If you are looking for something like this you need to use ajax call or json for accessing the php file that can take the data from your database. And push in to the html.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get information from your WordPress database to a script you'll need to use AJAX to pass that information from PHP to the JavaScript.

WordPress and AJAX in the WordPress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

WordPress AJAX template I use: https://gist.github.com/theantichris/6600226